# If sets of unbiased coin flips follow a normal distribution, why would they not influence your guess as to Heads or Tails?

Tags: probability

If we have $1,000$ sets of $10$ coinflips, and look at the frequency of the total Heads and Tails, the most common would be $5H$-$5T$. Given the different probabilities of each set occurring, how would this not "influence" the $10$th flip in a set that had $9T$ in a row, given it is less likely that you are in a set with $10T$ as opposed to $9T$-$1H$? Intuitively this seems wrong and I'd like to know why.

Comment: Coins don't have memories.  Each individual coin flip is independent of previous coin flips.

Answer (score 1):

While there are 10 arrangements of 9 tails and 1 head, only one of them has the *first* 9 flips being tails. The 10th flip takes the options $\{9T1H, 10T\}$. At that point you can no longer get, say, $3T1H6T$ or any of the other 9 arranagements, because the first 9 flips already happened.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand that the 10th flip is independent from the first nine, just on general principles. But we can also see the flaw in the specific argument to the contrary:

- It is definitely true that in 10 tosses of a coin, getting *a total of* 9 tails and 1 head is much more likely than getting *a total of* 10 tails and 0 heads.
- However, getting 9 tails *in a row* followed by 1 head has exactly the same likelihood as getting 10 tails *in a row*.